# Issue on click event after hover out on toggling two classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is the first click on `.dropper` after hovering out of `.dropdown-menu` not working?

Steps to produce the issue:

1- Click on Action A button (The dropdown menu should slide down and the arrow turn to down angle) 
2- Hover out over Dropdown (The dropdown should slide up and the arrow back to right angle) 
3- Again click on Action A button (The dropdown slide down **but** arrow  **stays in right angle** )

I am trying to handle the animation on 3 levels

1- Direct Click on .dropper
2- Out Click on Body
3- Hover out the .dropdown-menu

Looks like I am getting the issue on

```
$("body").on("hide.bs.dropdown", function (e) {
  var i = $(e.relatedTarget).find(".fa");
  i.removeClass("css-chevron-down").addClass("css-chevron-right");
});
```

which I am trying to toggle dropdown and animations when user click somewhere else.

```js
$(".dropper").on('click', function () {
  $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('css-chevron-right css-chevron-down');
  let $this = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu");
  $(".dropdown-menu").not($this).slideUp(300);
  $this.slideToggle(300);
});

$(".dropdown-menu").hover(function (e) {}, function (e) {
  $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp(500);
  $(".fa").removeClass("css-chevron-down").addClass("css-chevron-right");
});
$("body").on("hide.bs.dropdown", function (e) {
  var i = $(e.relatedTarget).find(".fa");
  i.removeClass("css-chevron-down").addClass("css-chevron-right");
});
```

```css
.css-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.css-chevron-right {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-6 "><div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropper" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action A <i class="fa fa-chevron-right css-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="float:left; margin-left:200px;"><div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropper" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action B <i class="fa fa-chevron-right css-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code:

**1)** First I remove the listener on event `hide.bs.dropdown` since the logic inside this listener can be approached on the click event of a `dropper`.

**2)** I have correctly target the related elements, since most of the time, you was targeting all elements with some class, for example, `dropdown-menu` and `fa` on the hover out listener of a `dropdown-menu`.

Check next example:

```js
$(".dropper").on('click', function()
{
    $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('css-chevron-down');
    let $this = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu");

    $(".dropdown-menu").not($this).slideUp(300)
        .prev(".dropper").find(".fa").removeClass("css-chevron-down");

    $this.slideToggle(300);
});

$(".dropdown-menu").hover(function (e) {}, function (e)
{
    $(this).slideUp(500);
    $(this).prev(".dropper").find(".fa").removeClass("css-chevron-down");
});

/*
$("body").on("hide.bs.dropdown", function (e)
{
    var i = $(e.relatedTarget).find(".fa");
    i.removeClass("css-chevron-down");
});
*/
```

```css
.css-chevron-down {
    transform: rotate(0.25turn);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.css-chevron-right {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-6 "><div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropper" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action A <i class="fa fa-chevron-right css-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="float:left; margin-left:200px;"><div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropper" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action B <i class="fa fa-chevron-right css-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
</div>
```